# Replacing values in the list (lists overlap)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Okay, output maybe isn't clear if you don't know the language. Here is example:

```
        0       1       2         3       4
x = ['text1','text2','text3'  ,'text4','text5']   - scrapped_sentence[-30+position:position+30], where position is taken from re.finditer
y = [  '-'  ,  '-'  ,['text1'],  '-'  ,['text2']] - texts from re.findall
out=[  '-'  ,  '-'  ,  text1  ,  '-'  , 'text2']  - scrapped sentence
```

---

Problem:

I'm trying to figure out the code that would replace one list with another on places that are not minuses.

List of indexes of the first list: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]`

List of indexes of the second list: `[37, 39, 41, 42, 43, 50, 63, 69]`

First list:

`['gospodarcze:  gospodarcze ', 'parking:  parkingo', 'parking:  parkingo', 'garaż:  garaże', 'garaż:  garaże', 'garaż:  garaże', 'garaż:  garaże', 'ogród:  ogród.', 'ogród:  ogród.', 'ogrod: ,ogrode', 'ogrod: ,ogrode', 'remon:  remont', 'aneks:  anekse', 'aneks:  anekse', 'zabudow:  zabudowi', 'zabudow:  zabudowi']`

In first list there will be more characters (sentences +/-60 chars.). Here is short (+/1 char.) for better view.

Second list:

`['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', ['gospodarcze'], '-', ['parking', 'parking'], '-', ['garaż', 'garaż', 'garaż', 'garaż'], ['ogród', 'ogród'], ['ogrod', 'ogrod'], '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', ['remon'], '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', ['aneks', 'aneks'], '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', ['zabudow', 'zabudow'], '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']`

Desired output is overlaping the list. I know it is kind of impossible right now, because First list should have some nested values such as `'parking:  parkingo', 'parking:  parkingo`. Still working on it.

`['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', 'gospodarcze:  gospodarcze', '-', ('parking:  parkingo', 'parking:  parkingo'), '-', ('garaż:  garaże', 'garaż:  garaże', 'garaż:  garaże', 'garaż:  garaże'), ('ogród:  ogród.', 'ogród:  ogród.'), ('ogrod: ,ogrode', 'ogrod: ,ogrode'), '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', remon:  remont, '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', (aneks:  anekse', 'aneks:  anekse'), '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', ('zabudow:  zabudowi', 'zabudow:  zabudowi), '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']`

I was trying this code:

```
for h in position_list_k: #postion_list_k = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
    for n, i in enumerate(lista_j):
        if i != '-':
            lista_j[n] = lista_k[h]
#lista_k - 1st list, lista_j - 2nd
```

Tried also:

```
jk = []
for i in lista_j:
    if i == '-':
        jk.append(lista_j)
    else:
        jk.append(lista_k)
print(jk)
```

But the output (first attempt) is this:

`['gospodarcze:  gospodarcze ', 'parking:  parkingo', 'parking:  parkingo', 'garaż:  garaże', 'garaż:  garaże', 'garaż:  garaże', 'garaż:  garaże', 'ogród:  ogród.', 'ogród:  ogród.', 'ogrod: ,ogrode', 'ogrod: ,ogrode', 'remon:  remont', 'aneks:  anekse', 'aneks:  anekse', 'zabudow:  zabudowi', 'zabudow:  zabudowi']`

`['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', 'zabudow:  zabudowi', '-', 'zabudow:  zabudowi', '-', 'zabudow:  zabudowi', 'zabudow:  zabudowi', 'zabudow:  zabudowi', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', 'zabudow:  zabudowi', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', 'zabudow:  zabudowi', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', 'zabudow:  zabudowi', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']`

If I put more indent on printing the lists I'll get 15 lists (`h`), with every other word from the first list, but with the same style.

**The main issue in this list is that the first list should have nested lists or tuples. If it was, both lists would have same number of indexes.**

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are trying to do. For the two sample lists you have given, can you also give the desired output?

Comment: here you go, edited. I'm working still, the length from both lists should be the same. First list will have tuples when it is used the same word. Sometimes in description of the page one word was used more than one time, and I'd like to have them all. Words from the first list will be extended to sentences.

Comment: At first your question sounds like you are just trying to compare two lists and replace items from the first list with any non "-" items at the same index from the second list. But then all the extra examples of what you have attempted on your own lead me to believe that you might be after something different - particularly your comment about nested lists and tuples. If you can clear it up a bit, then we may be able to help.

Comment: Yes you're right, I'm trying to compare two lists and replace items from the first list with any non "-" items at the same index from the second list. But the length of two lists are different. If there will be tuples in the first list (same words like parking: parking == (parking,parking)) the length of the two lists will be the same. And then I'm will try to compare it.

Answer (score 0):

Lol guys I did. Sleeping is very helpful in coding. Here is the code:

```
#for j to 77:
for m in re.finditer(HEADERS[j], p):
            #print((m.start(),m.end()), m.group())
            m_start.append(m.start())
            m_end.append(m.end())
            x = m_start[0]
            y = m_end[0]
        #extra line (extra logic as benvc mentioned):
        if m_start and m_end != None:
            print(m_start,m_end,m.group())
```